# Font Awesome 5: Could not find icon money-check

Tags: angular, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I'm trying to load the icon "money-check" using angular-fontawesome; but getting message 
`FontAwesome: Could not find icon with iconName=money-check and prefix=fas`
Most other icons work; a few i've found that don't:

- money-check
- money-check-alt
- user-check

They are not listed as renamed under the [upgrade guide](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/upgrading-from-4).

My package.json:

```
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.1.0-10",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.0-11",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-8",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-8",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-8",
```

My app.module:

```
import {fas} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import {faPlayCircle, faThumbsUp, faThumbsDown} from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';

library.add(fas, faPlayCircle, faThumbsUp, faThumbsDown);
```

my html:
`<fa-icon class="icon type" icon="money-check" size="lg"></fa-icon>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @MBaas for pointing me down the right direction. I was following instructions on the [angular-fontawesome page](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome); and now reverted to the regular font awesome install. Here's the package.json that fixed it:

```
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.1.0-10",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands": "^5.0.13",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular": "^5.0.13",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid": "^5.0.13",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.0-11",
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [icon's page](https://fontawesome.com/icons/money-check?style=solid): it was added in 5.0.13 - and you seem to be using 5.1.0-8. [user-check](https://fontawesome.com/icons/user-check?style=solid) is from 5.1.0.11.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, your html is wrong.
You have

```
<fa-icon class="icon type" icon="money-check" size="lg"></fa-icon>
```

But it should be:

```
<fa-icon class="icon type" [icon]="faMoneyCheck" size="lg"></fa-icon>
```

check [icon]=

also, need to import that

Comment: Your solution gives this error: `Property 'faMoneyCheck' does not exist on type '...my component...'.`

Comment: you have to import the icon - `import { faMoneyCheck } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solve this problem adding in library.add() and import in the line correspondent the necessary icon, in your case would like the next code in your app.module.ts:

import {fas ***, faMoneyCheck***} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import {faPlayCircle, faThumbsUp, faThumbsDown} from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';

library.add(fas, faPlayCircle, faThumbsUp, faThumbsDown ***, faMoneyCheck***);

I hope this helps you, thanks and scuse me for my english.